# Create N length of array with values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am creating a N length array with value filled in, I am looking if I can improve the way I am doing it.

I get random number on the fly to determine the number of array item.

What I am doing is:

For example, if the number is 5.

```
let array = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  array.push(`item0${i}`)
}
```

Now, the array will be ['item01', 'item02, .... 'item05']

This looks quite long, can this be done is a shorter way?

Thanks

Comment: Define "shorter"... Less characters? Less lines? It can be done in "one line" but... Write readable, and well-formatted code. If you need it to be smaller then use a specialized tool for that.

Comment: @Andreas "If you need it to be smaller then use a specialized tool for that." Isn't that the point of the question? Additionally is the question off-topic on Stack Overflow? I don't think so, because I've literally seen a duplicate of the question which had hundreds of upvotes on SO before. The OP would be better served by pointing to the duplicate then playing hot potato and posting unhelpful comments.

Comment: @Peilonrayz _"This looks quite long, can this be done is a shorter way?"_ - This is not a problem. That just asks for a _"yes"_ or _"no"_ and, if at all, an opinion-based answer. Nothing that's in the scope of SO: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [new Array Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array).

```js
const arr = new Array(5)
```

This however will only create an array of length 5 without any entries. To use array methods on the array, you will first have to either [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) the array with valus, or create entries of value `undefined` using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

If you want to pre-populate the array:

```js
function makeArray(n) {
    return (new Array(n)).fill().map((el,ind) => `item0${ind}`)
}

makeArray(5);
```

Or even provide a callback as property so you can change what the pre-filled elements look like and use spread syntax to avoid the `.fill()` call:

```js
function makeArray(n, cb) {
    return [...new Array(n)].map((el,ind) => cb(ind))
}

makeArray(5, (ind) => `item0${ind}`);
```

Comment: @tonimora What makes this a "better" option than a simple `for` loop that you can understand just by looking at it?